# Jquery multiple tabbed boxes on one page

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I am still learning the basics of jQuery and I have managed to make this tabbed box work for a single tabbed box on a page, but I need to place several tabbed boxes on a page.
When I place more than one tabbed box on a page it hides all content on all the tabbed boxes apart from the selected tab.
How can I amend my jQuery so it hides the tabs on the selected tabbed area and does not hide all the content boxes on the other tabbed sections?

HTML :

```
<div id="tabbed_box_1" class="tabbed_box">
<div class="tabbed_area">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#" title="content_1" class="tab active">name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="content_2" class="tab">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="content_3" class="tab">skills</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content_1" class="content">
        <p>name 1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content_2" class="content">
      <p>about 1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content_3" class="content">
       <p>skills 1</p>
    </div>

</div><!--END Tabbed_area-->

 </div><!--END Tabbed_box_1-->

  <div id="tabbed_box_2" class="tabbed_box">
  <div class="tabbed_area">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#" title="content_4" class="tab active">name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="content_5" class="tab">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="content_6" class="tab">skills</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content_4" class="content">
        <p>name 2</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content_5" class="content">
      <p>about 2</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content_6" class="content">
       <p>skills 2</p>
    </div>

  </div><!--END Tabbed_area-->

  </div><!--END Tabbed_box_2-->
```

jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.tab").click(function () {

        // switch all tabs off
        $(".active").removeClass("active");

        // switch this tab on
        $(this).addClass("active");

        // slide all elements with the class 'content' up
        $(".content").slideUp();

        //Get attribute value and find the element with that id.  Then slide that down.
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#"+content_show).slideDown();

    });

    $("a.tab").focus(function () {

        // switch all tabs off
        $(".active").removeClass("active");

        // switch this tab on
        $(this).addClass("active");

        // slide all elements with the class 'content' up
        $(".content").slideUp();

        // Now figure out what the 'title' attribute value is and find the element with that id.  Then slide that down.
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#"+content_show).slideDown();

    });

  });
```

css:

```
ul.tabs {
margin: 5px 0 6px;
padding: 0;
}
ul.tabs li {
display: inline;
list-style: none outside none;
}
ul.tabs li a {
background-color: #464C54;
background-image: url("images/tab_off.jpg");
background-position: center bottom;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border: 1px solid #464C54;
color: #FFEBB5;
font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 9px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px 14px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover {
background-color: #2F343A;
border-color: #2F343A;
}

ul.tabs li a.active {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-color: #464C54 #464C54 #FFFFFF;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
color: #282E32;
}

.content {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #464C54;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
padding: 10px;
}

 #content_2, #content_3, #content_5, #content_6 {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the relevant CSS? Also, can you clarify which content you want to show and hide when a user clicks?

Comment: css added, i want to show the content in the divs content divs with ids like - content_4 , so when the button on the second tabbed section is clicked or focused, it shows content_4 div, but doesn't hide the content in tabbed_box_1 such as content_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find the answer. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/two-instances-of-tabs-on-one-page

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [jQuery plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/). For example:

```
$.fn.tabbedBox = function() {…}
```

And then you call this like:

```
$('.tabbed_box').tabbedBox()
```

Since within your plugin your bind your jquery calls to `this`, your code is reusable without affecting other elements on this page (such as your other tabbed boxes).

Comment: So i can just put all of the jQuery ive written into the $.fn.tabbedBox function {} and then it should work. How do i call the plugin within the page ?

Comment: I have put it into a plugin and it still is not working do you have any ideas why it wouldn't ?

Comment: We would need to see your new code. Can you add an update to your question or link to a source?